# Refine a search using aspx and dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need advice and/or examples on how to use a dropdown list to filter down to a selection of items  WITHOUT having to refresh the page.

So here's the scenario, I have a database table that has 3 columns and  40551 rows.  I have a web page where when you click a button it brings up an update panel with a dropdown list in which the client can make a selection from one of two hundred choices from Column A, this should then bring up a corresponding list of items from Column B where the client can make the second selection which will then show the corresponding items from Column C.

How can I do this without refreshing the main page?

is there some way to just refresh the update panel or is there something I am missing.

Or better, is there a way I can query Column C from the update panel and populate the dropdown without it interfering with the main page eg, client types "CAT" and I populate a list with all things in Column C starting with "CAT"

Iv tried researching but could not find any answers that don't involve refreshing the entire page.

Any help would be appreciated and I don't mind using jquery or javascript as long as it will work with asp.

Thanks

Comment: you use javascript and make call to a handler (.ashx) that returns the relative values...

Comment: The technology you're looking for is called AJAX.  At a high level, it uses JavaScript code to make requests to the server in the background, and handle the response from the server (where you can update page content, for example).  It will likely involve writing some JavaScript code (which you should get comfortable doing for web development), but there may be drag-and-drop components for ASP.NET as well.  You can search for things like "ASP.NET AJAX tutorials" or "ASP.NET AJAX examples" with your favorite search engine.  There are many examples to get you started.

Comment: Hi Aristos , David .   Thanks. I will look into .ashx and AJAX.  I kept googling "How to update a list with out refresh" and had no luck. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post the answer in case someone else had a similar issue.

I initially thought that refining via dropdowns would be the best option but thanks to @David for pointing me in the right direction with Ajax, I found an easier choice was to just put in a search textbox. Sometimes you need to know what you need to search for.

On the main page update panel I added a textBox and button and used the below to retrieve the info and update a dropdown select list :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#SearchTest').click(function () {
            var str = document.getElementById('<%= search.ClientID %>').value;
             var TestfirstSelectnameID = document.getElementById('<%= firstSelect.ClientID %>');
            var useThis =   true;  
            var xhttp;
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
                    TestfirstSelectnameID.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "productSearch.asp?q=" + str, true);
            xhttp.send(); 
            return false;
        });
 
</script>
```

This script will post to a .asp page :

```
<%

Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = local\Test; Initial Catalog = CompanyOnline; User Id = sa; Password=CompanyOnline123"

sql=" SELECT  ( [Description] +' - '+ [Code] ) as Item , [Code] FROM [CompanyOnline].[dbo].[Product] where ( [Description] like '" & request.querystring("q") & "%' or [Code] like '" & request.querystring("q") & "%' ) "
 
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open sql,conn
  
If conn.errors.count = 0 Then   
 
End If

dim leftCount  

leftCount = 1 

do until rs.EOF

  for each x in rs.Fields
 
 if leftCount MOD 2 then 
    response.write("<option value= " & rs.Fields(1).Value & ">" & rs.Fields(0).Value & "</option>" )
end if


    leftCount= leftCount+1 
  next
      rs.MoveNext 
   
loop
     
%>
```

The returned value will then populate an expanded drop-down list.

Using it this way I can either search for all items starting with "Cat" and it will populate the drop-down with "Cat Food", "Cat Basket" etc or I could use the code "CAT001" and it will just populate the dropdown with the single item.